# array is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...)

Tags: ios, swift

I just upgraded from swift 1.2 to 2.  Im getting an array' is unavailable: please construct an Array from your lazy sequence: Array(...) and I can't seem to wrap my ahead around how to fix this

```
MyVariables.selectedUser = MyVariables.dictionary.keys.array[indexPath.row] as String
```

What should "MyVariables.dictionary.keys.array[indexPath.row] as String" be changed to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's saying that the `array` property on the lazy sequence returned by `keys` is no longer available. In Swift 2, you use an initializer to convert the lazy sequence into an array:

```
MyVariables.selectedUser = Array(MyVariables.dictionary.keys)[indexPath.row] as String
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift1.2, values on Dictionary returns LazyForwardCollection> type that has .array property returning Array.

In Swift2, values on Dictionary returns LazyMapCollection<[Key : Value], Value>, and the .array property is abandoned because we can construct Array with Array(dict.values).

In this case you can use these lines

**let array = Array(arrayLiteral:myVariable!.keys)

var selectedUser = [indexPath.row]**